# unable to write a script to change the logo redirect url

Tags: development, javascript, master-page, custom-masterpage, site-logo

I am working on a web application which contain 2 site collections , with the following URLs:-

- `http//servername`
- `http://servername/HR`

and the second site collection have two subsites , with the following url:-

- `http://servername/HR/Staff`
- `http://servername/HR/manager`

now all of the above 4 sites (2 site collections + 2 subsites) have a site logo. now the default behavior is that clicking on the logo will redirect to the home page of the current site, either a site collection or sub site.

so i need to force the logo image to allow redirect to the root site collection , so i wrote the following script :-

```
$(document).ready(function () {


    $("a.ms-siteicon-a").attr("href", "/");
    $("a.ms-siteicon-a").attr("onclick", "");
});
```

and i reference it inside all the sites master pages. but i got this behavior;-

1. on IE the above script will work on the site collection. so if i am inside the HR site collection and i click on the logo i will redirect to the root `http://servername/` instead of `http://servername/HR/` which is correct. while on firefox the logo for the HR will keep redirecting to `http://servername/HR`
2. on both IE & Firefox, if i am inside a sub site such as `http://servername/HR/staff` the logo will keep redirecting to the subsite home page instead of the root as mentioned on the script.

so can anyone adivce how to force the logo on all the sites to always redirect to the root ?

Thanks

Comment: In SharePoint terminology http:// servername/HR is not a site collection but a subsite (even if it contains subsites).    On the same web application you will have a site collection like this "http:// servername".  Other site collections will have a url like this "http:// servername/sites/anothersitecol1" or "http:// servername/sites/anothersitecol2". It doesn't answer the question but it is good to know ;)

Comment: are you sure that your script updates the html of the Logo-Link?

Comment: @Sylvain not sure if this is correct now if i create a site collection under /HR/ where HR is an Explicit inclusion managed path , then why u consider servername/hr/ as a subsite.. i did not get your point !

Comment: Well in that case you are right, sorry I thought it was a beginner terminology mistake ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `JavaScript` we can make respective changes in `master page`.
Assuming you are on `SharePoint 2013 on-premise`. If you notice in the `seattle.master` file, you can find a div with ID `siteIcon` which is responsible for redirection. Refer below.

```
<div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
    <SharePoint:AjaxDelta id="DeltaSiteLogo" BlockElement="true" runat="server">
        <SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink CssClass="ms-siteicon-a" runat="server" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic" >
            <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/_layouts/15/images/siteIcon.png?rev=23" runat="server"/>
        </SharePoint:SPSimpleSiteLink>
    </SharePoint:AjaxDelta>
</div>
```

Now to customize the redirection, firstly I have my own custom master page, where I have replaced the above `AjaxDelta` control to `SPLinkButton` which allows me to specify the Navigate Url.

```
NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/"
```

The above attribute value will redirect to `root`. Refer below full div structure.

```
<div id="siteIcon" class="ms-tableCell ms-verticalAlignTop">
    <SharePoint:SPLinkButton runat="server" NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/" id="onetidProjectPropertyTitleGraphic">
        <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage name="onetidHeadbnnr0" id="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="/Style%20Library/Images/Logo.png" ToolTip="Home" AlternateText="Logo" runat="server"/>
    </SharePoint:SPLinkButton>
</div>
```

Comment: your solution will Redirect to the RootWeb of the current Sitecollection. That is not what he want. He seems to want to always Redirect to the RootWeb of the Sitecollection in the Webapplications Root

Comment: @LeopoldLerch yes exactly i want to always redirect to the root url which is "http://servername"

Comment: @Asad now i tried adding the SPlinkButton as you mentioned but i got the following error :- "The ID 'DeltaSiteLogo' is already used by another control. "

Comment: @johnG Did you use the last snippet in answer? You should be using that, and this do not contain DeltaSiteLogo as we are replacing it.

Comment: @johnG Did that solve your problem?

Comment: @AsadRefai although i was searching for a javaScript based solution but seems it will not work , or i can not find any.but ur solution worked 100% well on all the sites collections and sub sites ,, thnaks

Comment: @AsadRefai but for my case i added this NavigateUrl="/" instead of NavigateUrl="~sitecollection/" . as in my case i want to redirect to the root site collection ..

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your RootSite is located at the Servers Root, you could simply Change your masterpage where your SiteLogoImage is situated to:

```
<a class="ms-siteicon-a" href="/">
      <SharePoint:SiteLogoImage CssClass="ms-siteicon-img" name="onetidHeadbnnr0" ID="onetidHeadbnnr2" LogoImageUrl="images/Logo_t.png" runat="server" />
</a>
```

So you won´t Need the JavaScript anymore

Comment: but i was searching for a way to apply this change inside a javascript and reference this javascript from all the master pages, this will be a cleaner solution. as my current javascript contain many customizations, and i do not need to apply the customization on each master page , i just reference the javascript on all the master pages, and have a centralized control for all the changes. of course if the change can not be achieved using javascript then the last choice will be to modify the master page itself.. thanks.

Comment: sry, I don´t get your Point. You create custom masterpages for all the sites, and then attach a Javascript which again changes the already customized pages again on Client side?. that doesn´t Sound centralized to me at all.

Comment: however, then you will have to debug the JavaScript. Maybe it is executed too soon. the document.ready function does not work well in relation to SharePoint, as SharePoint does many Renderings clientside (which also happens AFTER document is loaded). you should consider the SharePoint built in equivalents like "_spBodyOnLoadFunctionNames".

Comment: somehow it is centralized, now let say i want to change the redirect URL to a specific page in the future,  then i can do so from the javascript itself and have the effect on all the master pages which reference the javascript. but if i am changing the master pages themselves then i will end up modifying all the master pages to chnage the redirect URL, also if i want to return back to the defualt behavior where each logo redirect to the current site (SC or subsite) , then i can comment the related code on the script file instead of modifying all the master pages,, did u get my point ?